# I want that two span tags to have the same vertical position

Tags: html, css

Whole code : http://jsfiddle.net/3TQq6/

I'm making theme for my blog.
In the title part, there is a problem.

```
<div class="post_title">
    <br/>
    <h2><a href="[##_article_rep_link_##]">[##_article_rep_title_##]</a></h2>
    <span class="post_cate">나만보기</span>
    <span class="post_date">[##_article_rep_date_##]</span>
</div>
```

h2 tag will show the title of the article.
first span tag will show the category of the article. 
second span tag will show when the article upload.

They are in one line.
h2 and span starts from left side, second span starts from right side because of float.

When I run the code, two spans have different vertical position.

http://goo.gl/vZwSzz

second span is placed higher than the first span.
I want that two span tags have the same vertical position.
but don't move first span tag. I want to adjust the second to the first.

How can I move the second span?

Comment: When you say same vertical positioning to did you want the bottom to be aligned or all of it to be centered?

Comment: Are they supposed to be on the same line?

Comment: @jerrylow I want bottom. http://goo.gl/1PPnwv -like this.

Comment: @Sam Yes. like this : http://goo.gl/1PPnwv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3TQq6/2/)

**Remove** `float: right` from `.post_date`, and then add the following css rules:

```
.post_title {
    position: relative;
}

.post_date {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6px;        /* Adjust this to match the height of .post_cate */
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do it. One is to keep the float right and position it properly with margin-top pushing the date down:

```
.post_date {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

This positions it when everything is all on one line, but if there's multiple lines the date will be off. The second method is to use position: absolute to align it to the bottom:

```
.post_title {
    position: relative;
}

.post_date {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 9px;
}
```

Results: http://jsfiddle.net/3TQq6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/3TQq6/4/)

```
<div class="post_title">
  <br/>
  <h2><a href="[##_article_rep_link_##]">[##_article_rep_title_##]</a></h2>
  <span class="post_cate">나만보기</span>
  <span class="post_date">[##_article_rep_date_##]</span>
  <br/>
</div>
```

---

```
.post_title h2 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
.post_title span {
  color: #bababa;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.post_cate {
  float: left;
}
.post_date {
  float: right;
}
```